# How to monkeypatch env variable correctly in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching, pytest-mock

I have some environment variable set that I need to mock when running my tests but when I try using `monkeypatch.setenv` it just doesn't work and keep fetching the variables from `.env` file. I even tried `delenv` before but still can't figure out how to set the test env variables correctly. I've used the `setattr` before and it worked just fine but can't figure out how to do env patching correctly.

The test fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def engine(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.delenv('DATABASE_URL', raising=False)
    monkeypatch.setenv('DATABASE_URL', 'postgres://root:password@localhost:5432/db_name')
    return DatabaseEngine().get()
```

The .env file contains that `DATABASE_URL` which is saved to a variable named `DB_CONFIG`
in a module named `config`

```py
    load_dotenv()
    DB_CONFIG = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
```

and used in the `DatabaseEngine`.

It's not the first time that I tried to monkeypatch the env variables and failed, any clue how to proceed please ?

Comment: Yuo have to patch `DB_CONFIG` instead of the environment variable, as that is what is used and initialized before the patching.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you that worked just fine, I've been loosing my mind over it for a while.